# C++ dynamic, array based stack

Tags: c++, arrays

Im just starting to learn C++ programming and for exercise i found this task. I have to write a dynamic, array based stack. This is what i have got so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CStack
{
private:
    char *bottom_;
    char *top_;
    int size_;
public:
    CStack(int n = 20){
        bottom_ = new char[n];
        top_ = bottom_;
        size_ = n;
    }
    int getSize(){ return size_; }
    void push(char c){
        if (!full()){
            *top_ = c;
            top_++;
        }
        else{
            resize(size_ * 2);
            *top_ = c;
            top_++;
        }
    }
    void resize(int newSize){

            //Allocate new array and copy in data
            char *newArray = new char[newSize];
            memcpy(newArray, bottom_, size_);

            //Delete old array
            delete[] bottom_;
            //Swap pointers and new size
            memcpy(bottom_, newArray, newSize);
            size_ = newSize;
            cout << "array has been resized" << endl;
    }

    int num_items() {
        return (top_ - bottom_);
    }
    char pop(){
        top_--;
        return *top_;
    }
    int full() {
        return (num_items() >= size_);
    }
    int empty() {
        return (num_items() <= 0);
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "Stack currently holds " << num_items() << " items: ";
        for (char *element = bottom_; element<top_; element++) {
            cout << " " << *element;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    ~CStack(){ // stacks when exiting functions
        delete[] bottom_;
    }
};
int main(){
    CStack s(5);
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push('s'); s.push('t'); s.push('a'); s.push('c'); s.push('k');
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push('='); 
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    cout << "Popped value is: " << s.pop() << "\n";
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push('!');
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.pop();
    s.pop();
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    while (!s.empty()) s.pop();
    if (s.num_items() != 0) {
        cout << "Error: Stack is corrupt!\n";
    }
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    // destructor for s automatically called
    system("pause"); // execute M$-DOS' pause command
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine untill the array is full and i resize it. After that instead of letters it starts printing this [image: printout] . And when the program is done and i have to press any key to exit it gives the following error [image: error]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When debugging it, what did you find? Which part of the code is not working as expected, how is it actually working, and what behavior is expected?

Comment: `delete[] bottom_;memcpy(bottom_, newArray, newSize);` is simply wrong

Comment: The bug is somewhere in the resize() function. Without it it works fine.

Comment: In a nutshell, you’re C-ifying your code. In C++, don’t use `memcpy`, eschew raw pointers owning memory, and decouple concerns. Start by a stack that does *not* manage its own memory. That’s a different responsibility entirely, and should be abstracted away. Also, don’t prefix your classes with “`C`”, that’s meaningless, and the convention is based on a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is indeed in the `resize` method:

```
void resize(int newSize){
    //Allocate new array and copy in data
    char *newArray = new char[newSize];
    memcpy(newArray, bottom_, size_);

    // Set the top to the new array
    top_ = newArray + (top_ - bottom_);

    // Delete old array
    delete[] bottom_;

    // Update pointers and size
    bottom_ = newArray;
    size_ = newsize;

    cout << "array has been resized" << endl;
}
```

Your code forgot to fix `top_` pointer and used `memcpy` to update the pointers when instead simple assignment is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should set top_ to new storage top in resize().

```
void resize(int newSize){

            //Allocate new array and copy in data
            char *newArray = new char[newSize];
            memcpy(newArray, bottom_, size_);

            top_ = newArray + (top_ - bottom_);

            //Delete old array
            delete[] bottom_;

            size_ = newSize;
            bottom_ = newArray;

            cout << "array has been resized" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: your `delete[] bottom_;` line is deleting the new array

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just ran the code with this version of resize() and the result is exactly the same.